# Will YARN working on NUMA respect node memory locality?

Tags: hadoop-yarn, numa, giraph

I'm working with the Giraph-based application that makes heavy use of memory in a NUMA system. It frequently writes and reads to the memory and has multiple threads. Assuming I schedule 4 workers with as many cores as there are cores per chip would that mean they would be pinned to specific CPU so that they can only use local NUMA memory?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what version of YARN are you using. Since YARN 3.1.0, you can enable NUMA scheduling in config. Patch can be found here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-5764